# How do you import svg file with svg tag?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I would like to know how to use svg file and use it as  tag. For example, I have a svg file like

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="512" height="512" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
<title></title>
<g id="icomoon-ignore">
</g>
<path d="M144 288h-32v224h32c8.8 0 16-7.2 16-16v-192c0-8.8-7.2-16-16-16z"></path>
</svg>
```

I am trying to require it with javascript (node, electron) and render in html  tag.

```
// For examle,
<svg src="./mySvg.svg" />
```

I don't want to use `<img>` tag or etc.

Comment: maybe put a rect tag inside svg tag and give it a background img using css?

Comment: What's the reason for not wanting to use `<img>`? That's the proper way of doing it. While Paul's answer below works, `<img>` would be the proper way of doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are excluding using `<img>` (HTML) or `<image>` (SVG), and presumably `<object>` as well, then the only other option is `<use>`:

```
<svg width="512" height="512" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
  <use xlink:href="#icomoon-ignore"/>
</svg>
```